# Rails query using dynamic column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got this method that's working fine.  But it feels like an opportunity for me to improve my Ruby skills.

In my app, students can be given bucks for a specific seminar, or for their whole school.  When it comes time to total up how many bucks a student has received, I run this method.

```
def bucks_owned(category, source)
    if category == "giver"
        return self.currencies.where(:giver => source).sum(:amount)
    else
        return self.currencies.where(:school => source).sum(:amount)
    end
end
```

It seems like Ruby would allow for a dynamic column in the query.  I've tried this, but it didn't work as I hoped.

```
def bucks_owned(category, source)
    self.currencies.where(:"#{category}" => source).sum(:amount)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
def bucks_owned(category, source)
  self.currencies.where(category => source).sum(:amount)
end
```

Comment: Eh. How is it different from `:"#{category}"` applied to Rails?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's different.  But this syntax worked.  Where my attempted syntax did not.

Comment: To be honest I think that should work too and I tried also :D Anyway, this is simple

Comment: From OP's code, it can be assumed that `category` is a String object, therefore the main difference is that OP's is (just an example): `where(giver: => source)`, while this answer is `where('giver' => source)`. They are different, but as far as I know, Rails accept both `String` and `Symbol` keys to the where clause, of which I am now curious why this seems to only work for Jeff's while the symbol doesn't work, as he said.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario there should literally be no difference (other than unnecessary overhead in the OP) since `where` will convert the keys in the options `Hash` to `String` in one way or another.

Comment: References for above comment: [Rails 5 uses `stringify_keys!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause_factory.rb#L17), [Rails 4 uses `to_s`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L38) (*also in attribute aliasing). [Rails 3 uses `to_s`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L16)

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry I should have clarified what I said. They are different in that one is a `Symbol` and the other one is a `String`. I could write a method where it only works for a `Symbol`, while it doesn't work for `String`, vice-versa, or both works. Although, as I have said and as you have said as well behaviour-wise, they are exactly the same. (I didn't know though that Rails convert the keys  to strings as I was always just wondering if `.to_s` is used or `.to_sym` or Rails somehow converts the argument into a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so thanks; good to know! :)